# C# Null reference exception when using a void function

Tags: c#, listview

I'm sure I've got something wrong here but nobody in my team can explain what it is. My goal is to be able to populate a listView item from a button click in another form however a null reference exception is thrown when passing the variables to form1 (System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.')

here is my code: Form1:

```
    AddRec addRec = new AddRec();
    public AddRec AddRec { get; set; }
    public static string viewItem1, viewItem2, viewItem3 = "";

    public void YesClick()
    {
        ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(viewItem1);
        lvi.SubItems.Add(viewItem2);
        lvi.SubItems.Add(viewItem3);
        listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
    }
```

Form2(AddRec):

```
    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        name = txtNameF.Text.ToLower() + " " + txtNameS.Text.ToLower();
        if (name != "")
        {
            num = txtNum.Text;
            mobileNum = txtModNo.Text;

            Form1.viewItem1 = name;
            Form1.viewItem2 = num;
            Form1.viewItem3 = mobileNum;
            Form1.YesClick();

            txtNameF.Text = "";
            txtNameS.Text = "";
            txtNum.Text = "";
            txtModNo.Text = "";
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Fields Required", "Warning");
        }
    }
```

The idea is that the add button on AddRec populates a listView in Form1 with the text from text boxes in AddRec. The exception is thrown on the Form1.YesClick()

Comment: Well, `YesClick()` is not a static method and needs `Form1` object reference! `viewItem1` etc are static and come with the class memory. So, to answer, just make `YesClick()` static and it will work.

Comment: Not quite clear from you code but, `ListViewItem` has a `Subitems` collection check if this is null rather than adding to it directly ( `lvi.SubItems.Add(viewItem2);`)

Comment: Changing the YesClick() function to static makes listView1 unreadable to the function so cannot add to the listview. Any additional info is very much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot call Form1 like that. You need to call the **"opened Form1"** before populating or changing it's properties. Try this:

```
Form1 frm = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form1>().Take(1).FirstOrDefault();
if (frm != null)
{
  //Populate all your properties here:
  frm.viewItem1 = name;
}
```

Comment: Is there a library you are using in this example? my IDE doesn't recognize the keyword Application

Comment: Are you using WinForm?

Comment: Make sure you are using this: using System.Windows.Forms;

Comment: I am using this library however copy pasting your code into my project, 'Application' is still not recognized

Comment: I corrected my code. That should work fine now.

Comment: Let me know if it works now.

Comment: Works a treat :) thank you very much. the current form check has helped tons in different areas. Sidenot: I had to give the namespace for a windows forms application since I was using Microsoft Excel objects but your code runs perfect.

Comment: You are welcome, glad to help :)